# Keyboard not working on a Samsung 300e5a laptop

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, laptop, samsung

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Samsung 300e5a laptop. The keyboard was not available during the installation, i don't know why, so i thought that it was just a glitch, and i used to virtual keyboard to finish the installation ( login, password ... )

I thought that the keyboard will be enabled at boot, but it still doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved this problem.
First, i noticed that booting with acpi=off at grub worked. But it wasn't a good solution because my fan wasn't working well.
So this is how i did :

At grub, add this 2 options :

- acpi=noirq
- acpi_iso=Linux ( needed if your fan stop working after using first option)

  - [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter)

Hope that it can help

Answer (score 1):

Going into the BIOS settings and turning on my touchpad from there seemed to work for me. Beforehand, I had the EXACT experience you did during the install and post-install.

Once I changed, my keyboard worked without a problem.