# Upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 loses keyboard and mouse

Tags: wireless, 12.04, keyboard, mouse

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04, and somehow its lost keyboard and mouse support, Logitech EX110 Cordless, preventing me from logging in, both the main and recovery mode won't respond to any keys at all, the previous kernal recovery mode does see the keyboard. Can I reverse this fatal upgrade somehow? Using the 12.04 live CD does work, but upon trying a reinstall, it hangs on "reinstalling previously installed packaged", which don't seem to install because "You have held broken packages".

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125903/keyboard-not-working-with-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 3):

Upon upgrade I was unable to use my Logitech MX550 wireless keyboard and mouse.

Using [information from this site](http://blog.neolocus.com/2012/04/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-and-logitech-dinovo-keyboard-issue/), I was able to gain full use of my mouse and keyboard as follows:

1. I booted into Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop.
2. Booted into Ubuntu on my laptop.
3. Used `ssh` on my laptop to log into my desktop.

   - After logging in via `ssh` but before performing step 4, you may need to use `lsusb` to determine your receiver's product ID. Mine is `c71[34]`. Another user with a similar situation had product ID `c52b`.
4. Created a new file with the command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules
   ```
5. Added the following lines to the file:

   ```
   ACTION=="remove", GOTO="hid2hci_end"
   SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="hid2hci_end"

   # Logitech devices
   KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c71[34]", \
   RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"

   ENV{DEVTYPE}!="usb_device", GOTO="hid2hci_end"

   LABEL="hid2hci_end"
   ```

   - If your product ID is not `c71[34]`, then replace that with your product ID (which you may have obtained with `lsusb` as described above).
6. Saved the file.
7. Reloaded the rule as root with:

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   ```
8. Rebooted the desktop to find my mouse and keyboard working (instead of rebooting, reattaching the keyboard/mouse dongle works too).

*alternately you can run the following to reset the dongle

```
modprobe -r hid_logitech_dj
modprobe hid_logitech_dj
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with my MBP running Ubuntu.  Here's what I did -- hopefully it'll work for you.  I solved these problems, but right now my monitor isn't playing nice with it, so I still have to fix that.

First of all, on boot, press "e" when selecting your partition to edit the boot parameters.  Look for something that says "quiet splash" and confirm that "text" is not appended to the end of that.  Shouldn't be by default, but I had added it at one point.

Second, boot.  When the Ubuntu logo splash screen pops up, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (you might also need the Function key pressed if you're on a laptop).  In the terminal, login and run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will probably run for awhile, so let it go.  Hopefully your computer's fans will be working (at this point, I noticed mine didn't, and I received a warning during the update that my CPU temperature was above the threshold and that the clock would be throttled.  If that happens, try [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed) -- it should work for your computer.  If you're on a Mac, you'll have to do something slightly different.

Your networking probably won't be working, either, but after the `apt-get` command runs, reboot and it should work again.

After that process, my computer is running it fine, though I have to manually watch the temperature and set the fans accordingly.  My only problem was one time that my monitor went blank, as though it had set the display to sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but couldn't get a usable console like previosly described.

Instead I made a 12.04 USB boot image. Due to the fact that this image did actually work on my laptop Asus EEE 1215B I continued opening a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) from where I was able to mount my harddisk (see /etc/fstab for details) Om my PC it was /dev/sda1.

So I did:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/xx
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/xx
```

Afwards I made a

```
sudo - root
chroot /tmp/xx
```

I then made an

```
su - 'mynormalusername'
```

followed by

```
export PATH=/sbin:$PATH
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This one halted at some point due to 'too many errors'. I tryed a couple of times but didn't seem to come any further so I tryed rebooting. And guess what, I can use my PC again.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't accept a `-` option. Running `sudo - root` yields the error `sudo: -: command not found`. You may want to edit your answer to change this to whatever command accomplishes what you're trying to do. (I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, which is why I have not made this change myself. But it seems to me that you could just put `sudo` in front of the `chroot` command and delete the `sudo - root` command from your instructions altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It is likely that the upgrade was interrupted and hence did not complete (which was what had happened in my case as my system crashed during upgrade). At the command prompt, please type:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It will install the rest of the upgrades and once you reboot, the issues are resolved.