# Running on low graphics mode after kernel upgrade

Tags: graphics, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 (alongside Windows 7). Two days back, 12.04 was running fine. Then it told me to please reboot so updates (I think only the kernel got upgraded at this time) could be applied. On reboot, I get the message

> your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure them yourself.

At this point, the Keyboard and Mouse are not functional, so I cannot click anything or configure anything.

During Boot, when Grub comes up, the keyboard works just fine, letting choose which Kernel version I want or to boot Windows.

I tried starting with previous kernels, but that did not work either.

My system has an Intel i5 and integrated Intel HD graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help...
[Upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 loses keyboard and mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127410/upgrading-to-ubuntu-12-04-loses-keyboard-and-mouse)

Before you try anything try booting up without mouse and keyboard to Ubuntu and after just reattach them.

For low graphics problem, go to Additional Drivers and try to reinstall or install driver if its not installed.