# Keyboard and Touchpad not working

Tags: gnome, asus, eeepc

My Eee PC will allow me to turn on the computer to login page, but I cannot get the keypad or the touch pad mouse to move. I have turned it off, taken out the battery then restarted it and the same happens. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Is that something related to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

I was having the exact same problem with Ubuntu 12.10 on an Asus Eee pc 1225. I've had some trouble with `ACPI` functions with this machine in the past. I'm no longer buying Asus products because they are poorly made.

Anyways, to fix this problem **I added a boot parameter to GRUB**. I found the suggested solution here:
[Keyboard not working on a Samsung 300e5a laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125903/keyboard-not-working-on-a-samsung-300e5a-laptop)

I tried adding `acpi=noirq` but that seemed to only re-enable the keyboard. The touchpad still didn't work. Next I tried `acpi=off`. That worked to get both keyboard and touchpad working. I also tried `acpi_osi=Linux` and that also worked. I tried rebooting and not changing the boot parameters and the keyboard and touchpad again didn't work. It only worked with `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi=off`. Your results may be different.

To change the boot parameters, check this link:
[How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Basically, when GRUB starts at boot, press <kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the editor. Find the line that starts with `linux` and add `acpi_iso=Linux` to the end of it, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then if that fixes your problem, *make the changes permanent* by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file. Find the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line and add `acpi_iso=Linux` to the end of the value on the right. Save, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

I hope that works out for you. Good luck.